# Multilingual site on Nuxt + Laravel with locales from backend

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am making a multilingual site on `Nuxt` + `Laravel`. I want to have an option to set locales in the database and share these locales to `Nuxt` front. Is it possible?

I found `Nuxt` plugin `nuxt-i18n` which looks good, but locales are set in `nuxt.config.js` file and you cannot set data from api response in this file.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **Lazy-load translations** in **nuxt-i18n**

First, create a structure for languages similar to this:

```
nuxt-project/
├── lang/
│   ├── en-US.js
│   ├── es-ES.js
│   ├── fr-FR.js
├── nuxt.config.js
```

Then set the `nuxt.config` configuration. Note that you need to set `lazy: true` and the `langDir`

```
// nuxt.config.js

['nuxt-i18n', {
  locales: [
    {
      code: 'en',
      file: 'en-US.js'
    },
    {
      code: 'es',
      file: 'es-ES.js'
    },
    {
      code: 'fr',
      file: 'fr-FR.js'
    }
  ],
  lazy: true,
  langDir: 'lang/'
}]
```

Then, inside the lang files you can call your API and return the json with the translation messages, like this:

```
// lang/[lang].js

export default (context) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    //Call your API and resolve the content here
    resolve({
      //The JSON return from your API
    })
  });
}
```

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lazy-load-translations/)

Comment: Lack of example but gave a clue, somehow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529529/accessing-app-context-from-custom-js-files-for-fetching-locale-messages might help

Answer (score 1):

Base on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534495/889126

I have done as

```html
export default async function (context) {
  // axios is derived directly from lib instead of context
  const axios = require('axios').default;

  let localeMessages = null

  await axios.get(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/js/lang-km.json'
  ).then((result) => {
    localeMessages = result.data
  }).catch(() => {
    localeMessages = {}
  });

  return localeMessages
}
```

It's working, you can display on console and also on your NuxtJS app:

[image]

Remark: the API I response as JSON string, you can use any prefix, I just made as: `/api/js/lang-km.json` (just a name)