# Accessing app context from custom .js files for fetching locale messages

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I am building Vue.js application using Nuxt.js in SSR mode. I have `axios` and `vue-i18n` plugins in my project.

`nuxt.config.js` :

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  // some irrelevant configs
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'nuxt-i18n',
  ],
  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-EN.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        name: 'Deutsch',
        file: 'de-DE.js'
      }],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
    },
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'locales/',
    vuex: {
      moduleName: 'i18n',
      syncLocale: true,
      syncMessages: true,
      syncRouteParams: true
    },
  },
  /* Axios module configuration */
  axios: {}
}
```

As you see i18n is set to **lazy** loading. And messages are taken from `locales/en-EN.js` and `locales/de-DE.js` files. In the files I want to make a request to a backend-api which will serve me messages. `locales/en-EN.js` :

```
export default async function (context) {
  return await context.$axios.get('backend-api');
}
```

However when I load the page it says that `$axios` is undefined: `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. But as soon as I start switching between languages, application receives translations. So my guess is that server while attempting to access `$axios` from context fails, but on client (Browser) it succeeds. What is the correct way of accessing `$axios` module from Nuxt `context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess the problem is that locale files are called during injection of plugins (`i18n`) so `axios` is not yet available in the app context.

So I have found a workaround:

First, I have imported plain `axios` (in addition to nuxt module)

```
npm i axios -S
```

Then in locale files i have imported its instance inside export function:

```
// en-En.js
export default async function (context) {

  // axios is derived directly from lib instead of context
  const axios = require('axios').default;

  let localeMessages = null

  await axios.get(
      'backend-api'
  ).then((result) => {
    localeMessages = result.data
  }).catch(() => {
    localeMessages = {}
  });

  return localeMessages
}
```

Still not sure whether this is a valid way to do it, but for now it works

Comment: It does work, the problem is that e.g. the default parameters you set in the nuxt config are not set.

Comment: Thanks, I detail what I did in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136834/889126